# Andengine game music resumes on the lockscreen

Tags: android, andengine

I have developed a game using `andengine`

I am facing a problem when using the power `Button`. If I press the POWER `Button` while playing the game the screen turns off and the `onPause()` is called as expected. But when I press the `HOME` button or `POWER` button again to turn on the screen, `onResume()` method is called and but the `lockscreen` shows up.

In the `onResume()` method, I resume the music of the game.

So as a result `lockscreen` shows up , but the game music plays in the background. I do not want to play the music in the `lockscreen`. Please help me solving this.Thank you

Comment: http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2011/11/making-android-games-that-play-nice.html

Comment: @alextsc its a good tutorial..thank you. But for my case it doesn't do the job

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is here: [Activity handle when screen unlocked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9747564/activity-handle-when-screen-unlocked/9747602#9747602)

By registering a `BroadcastReceiver` filtering the `Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON`, `Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF` and `Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_PRESENT` actions, you will be able to handle these 3 cases:

- `Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF`: When the `POWER` button is pressed and the screen goes black.
- `Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON`: When the `POWER` button is pressed again and lockscreen is showed up.
- `Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_PRESENT`: When you pass the locksreen and are back in your game.

**However**, in my case (using a Galaxy S GT I9000 with Froyo 2.2) these actions are not called when dealing with the `HOME` button (and I think it's a general behavior).

One simple and quick (but maybe not the best) way to handle both `HOME` and `POWER` buttons to pause and resume your music could be to keep the `onPause` and `onResume` methods and use a simple boolean flag like this:

```
private boolean mPowerButton = false;

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    // Pause your music
    Log.d("Game activity", "Music paused");
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    if (!this.mPowerButton) {
        // Resume your music
        Log.d("Game activity", "[HOME button] Music resumed inside onResume");
    }
}

public class receiverScreen extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {
            // This is the lockscreen, onResume has been already called at this  
            // step but the mPowerButton boolean prevented the resumption of music
        }

        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
            LevelActivity.this.mPowerButton = true;
        }

        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT)) {
            // Resume your music
            Log.d("Game activity", "[POWER button] Music resumed inside ACTION_USER_PRESENT action");
            LevelActivity.this.mPowerButton = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanx for your reply but I could not make this work for me. Anyway I have fixed this out by using OnWindowFocusChanged() method instead of using OnResume().
Thank you