# How to know that my app is in foreground on screen unlock

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

Every-time i want to show an add screen after screen unlock on only if my application is in running sate i mean foreground (User currently uses it). I done this through

"**user_present  permission and the receiver**"

Its working fine on screen unlock. But the problem is it always shows me add screen.
Either my app is in foreground(ON) or is in background(OFF).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing I can think of is to have a broadcast receiver for the screen unlock event (details at [Activity handle when screen unlocked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9747564/activity-handle-when-screen-unlocked)) and once this broadcast is received it opens up the screen you want.